# layout of .settext function in word VBA

Tags: vba, ms-word

hopefully this is quite straightforward, i just can't seem to find an answer.

I have a userform that has 10 labels and textboxes that once completed i want to export into another document but in a particular layout

I have code that works fine
`

```
With New MSForms.DataObject

    .SetText label1.Caption + ": " + textbox1.Text + Chr(13) + textbox2.Text + Chr(10) + textbox3.Text....etc
```

my concerns is that the length of .settext will make it difficult to refer to later and I was wondering if it was possible to lay it out differently

i.e

.settext  Label1.caption + textbox1.text + Chr(13)
+ textbox2.text + Chr(13)
+ Textbox3.text etc etc

Although whenever i try that the code stops working.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you're looking for the following. You need a space plus an underscore before pressing Enter (or Shift+Enter - makes no difference). You may *not* break up something like textbox1.text. But anywhere there's a natural space, or you can break up a string (as illustrated with etc, below).

```
settext Label1.caption & textbox1.text & Chr(13) _
        & textbox2.text & Chr(13) _
        & Textbox3.text & "etc. " _
        & "etc."
```

Note that I've changed your + to &. In VBA you should concatenate text using the ampersand as you could get unexpected results if anything you're concatenating is numeric.